# What are the best search terms looking for SharePoint content on the web?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0

i've done some work in the SharePoint Server 2007 space and i'm pretty satisfied with the content on the two big search providers. Switching to SharePoint 2010 i'm curious to see what are the best search termns to get content related to the specific products?

I'm using/looking for the following terms:

SharePoint Server 2007

-> MOSS

Windows SharePoint Services V3

-> WSS, WSS3

SharePoint Server 2010

-> "SharePoint 2010", SP2010, SPF2010 and SPS2010

SharePoint Foundation 2010

-> WSS4

Can anyone help me to define the right set of terms?

Thanx

Bye Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "SharePoint 2010" within quotation marks will most likely get the best results. Acronyms for SharePoint 2010 are SP2010, SPF2010 and SPS2010 but they are not yet as well accepted as WSS or MOSS.

Comment: thanx wictor. but what "should" be the right term to use if i'm blogging about SharePoint 2010? Is there no need for a dedicated term?

Comment: Go for SharePoint 2010 if you are looking for hits. Use SharePoint Foundation 2010 or SharePoint Server 2010 to get more relevant hits.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SharePoint Services V3: WSS, WSS3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately due to Microsoft's confusing naming standards this is difficult. In addition, it's easy for bloggers to label content as for MOSS while it will also still apply to WSS. This can also happen in reverse.

Generally when searching for WSS specific content that keyword will be used so is pretty reliable. Looking for MOSS content I tend to use a format of `searchterm "SharePoint" OR "MOSS" OR "WSS"`.

As Wictor mentions, searching for SharePoint 2010 content is still tricky as the community hasn't decided on exactly what acronyms to use.

Comment: I think we shouldn'T wait for microsoft to make a acronyms. If the top SharePoint MVP's are willing to make a decision, the crowd will follow :-)